# I've been added to a Facebook chat group but I can't access it what can I do?

Tags: facebook-messenger

Can't get on it any ideas, definitely been added to the group but it isn't notifying me I'm on it and can't get on it

Comment: logout then login again. go to the group see what showing. you added or not..